# PDO Регистр названия колонки

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

Здравствуйте.

Есть таблица members, в ней колонка fullName. При вставке PDO ругается что нет такого поля. Меняю название на fullname все нормально.

```
$member =   ["fullName" =>  "Василий Пупкин"];
_DB::i()->insRow("INSERT INTO members (fullName) VALUES (:fullName)",$member);
```

Есть возможность обойти этот нюанс без переименования в базе?

Comment: обычно в БД составное имя таблиц и колонок пишут через нижнее подчеркивание, например `object_id` или `fill_factor`... т.е. в вашем случае `full_name` ...... хотя конкретно данное поле обычно пишется слитно, т.е. `fullname`

Comment: Да я то это понимаю, но понимание поздно пришло. Проект привязан к ключам форм в шаблонах. Начал миграцию на pdo и вуаля )

Comment: Ох.. по мне так проще немного времени потратить и в шаблонах переименовать и сделать как все)) Но. в теории вы можете воспользоваться [setAttribute](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.setattribute.php)  а конкретно `setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_CASE, PDO::CASE_NATURAL )`  ....... как пример http://stackoverflow.com/a/12587701/6104996  ..... если конечно у вас есть возможность у драйвера подкрутить что-то, иначе у вас выбора не останется как шаблоны фиксить

Comment: С атрибутами игрался, но это везде прописывать AS. Ладно, пойдем стандартизироваться. =))